# Insert 1's random into a column pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, random

I have a dataframe with 182 rows. I want to add a column to it full of 0's except for twelve 1's distributed random in the df. Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['x']=0
df.loc[df.sample(12).index.tolist(), 'x'] =  1
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer as it makes great use of native methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) for this

```py
# create members
contents = [1 for _ in range(12)] + [0 for _ in range(182 - 12)]
# shuffle contents in-place
random.shuffle(contents)
# add to df
df["colname"] = contents
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.choice` along with list comprehension:

```
import random
df['NEW_COL'] = [0]*182
df['NEW_COL'][[random.choice(range(182)) for x in range(12)]] = 1
```